# Answers improperly deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers

My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889468/eclipse-pydev-interpreter-does-not-exist-in-filesystem) should definitely not be deleted -- why was it?

The following question questions:

[PyDev fails to install on Eclipse for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641457/pydev-fails-to-install-on-eclipse-for-mac)

[Pydev Not Recognized in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827404/pydev-not-recognized-in-eclipse)

had the same correct answer and were also deleted when I don't think they should have been.  Why were they deleted when the answer is correct?

Comment: Comments should never hold content that should be part of an answer instead.

Comment: Comments are deleted for a number of reasons, for example when they are obsolete

Comment: Fabio's talking about deleted answers, one of which should indeed have been a comment, the other two appearing to say "use this other thing" rather than answering the actual question AFAICT.

Comment: Yeap, sorry, meant to say that I had answers added and not comments.

Comment: I'm surprised that someone with 400 answers and 225 comments doesn't know the difference between the two yet...

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question to quote the **answers**, for those of us with <10k on stack overflow

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Comments should never be thought to be permanent.

They are only a means to add information to a post and if they don't, they should be deleted.

Even if they **do** add information to a post, the information should be edited **into** the post.

Comments have always been a "second class" citizen on Stack Exchange sites, as they tend to promote discussion over pure Question & Answer, which is what our sites are all about.

---

Now, you seem to be talking about **answers** to questions - those answers were **low quality** - either link only or a very short sentence. Those **should** be removed as they are not up to the quality we expect from answers.

---

Now, after further digging, I find that you have posted **an identical answer** to several questions. This was **automatically** flagged and a moderator acted on this flag and deleted the posts.

Moral of the story: **do not copy-paste** answers. Make more of an effort to tailor your answers to the actual post. If multiple posts do indeed have the same answer, consider that they are **duplicates** of each other and should be closed as such, with one being the canonical question where the answer is posted.

Comment: He's referring to answers, not comments.

Comment: @Servy - Yeah. With the clarifying comments and looking at the posts, I added more to my answer. Hope you approve ;)

Comment: Actually, the first one said that the issue was a bug and asked to report it (I fail to see how that's low quality)

Comment: @FabioZadrozny It said it might be a bug, but that he wasn't sure.  Slightly different thank saying it's a verified bug.

Comment: The others were related at the current issue in PyDev installs (which is that PyDev requires a java 7 vm -- and points at LiClipse which is a pydev standalone with everything pre-configured and supported by PyDev developers, so, I fail to see why that's bad too)

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's a bug as I'm the current PyDev developer and I know what made that happen.

Comment: Ok, I flag all as duplicate -- but that doesn't explain the other one which was properly tailored...

Comment: @FabioZadrozny - the duplicate algorithm is somewhat fuzzy and will trigger on enough similarity in the posts.

Comment: Humm, can that one which was not duplicated be restored? It seems really strange (if you read it, you'll see it's very different from the others)

Comment: i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19911670/110451

Comment: @FabioZadrozny - I've undeleted that for you.

Comment: I didn't know that identical answers were automatically flagged. That's cool - and probably why I sometimes see *almost* identical answers.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Oded's answer here is of course correct. I am the one who deleted; and for the record, I do think I made a mistake with the one you linked just above, so I'm glad Oded restored that one.